# Could std::mutex::lock throw even if everything looks "good"?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, locking, mutex

From [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock), it isn't said explicitly that the lock function of `std::mutex` won't throw if the lock won't result in a dead lock.

[PThread's lock](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html) only have a deadlock error. I don't know for window's implementation of thread. I also don't know if they are other implementation of thread used as backend of `std::thread`/`std::mutex`.

So my question is "Should I write my code as if, some times, for no special reason, a lock may fail?".

I actually need to lock a mutex in some noexcept methods, and I want to be sure that they are noexcept.

Comment: +1 That a lock may throw is really not a good thing IMHO. Of course we need to call them in destructors. I ended up writing [my own mutex class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568990/locking-a-mutex-in-a-destructor-in-c11/16597680#16597680) after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a POSIX system, `std::mutex` will probably be implemented using POSIX mutexes, and `std::mutex::lock()` will eventually delegate to [`pthread_mutex_lock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html). Although C++ mutexes are not required to be implemented using POSIX mutexes, the authors of the C++ standard multi-threading seem to have modelled the possible error conditions on the POSIX error conditions, so examining those can be instructive. As [user hmjd says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551739/545127), the [C++ error conditions permitted for the `lock` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Mutex) are  `operation_not_permitted`, `resource_deadlock_would_occur` and `device_or_resource_busy`.

The POSIX error conditions are:

- `EINVAL`: if a POSIX specific lock-priorty feature is misused, which can never happen if you use only the standard C++ multi-threading facilities. This case *might* correspond to the `operation_not_permitted` C++ error code.
- `EINVAL`: if the mutex has not been initialized, which would correspond to a corrupted `std::mutex` object, use of a dangling reference, or some other undefined behaviour that indicates a program bug.
- `EAGAIN`: if the mutex is recursive and the recursion is too deep. That can't happen to a `std::mutex`, but could happen for a `std::recursive_mutex`. This would seem to correspond to the `device_or_resource_busy` error condition.
- `EDEADLK`: if deadlock would occur because of the thread already holds the lock. This would correspond to the `resource_deadlock_would_occur` C++ error code, but would indicate a program bug, because a program should not attempt to lock a `std::mutex` it already holds a lock on (use a `std::recursive_mutex` if you really want to do that).

The C++ `operation_not_permitted` error code is [evidently](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc) intended to correspond to the POSIX `EPERM` error status. The `pthread_mutex_lock()` function *never* gives this status code. But the POSIX manual page that describes that function also describes the `pthread_mutex_unlock()` function, which may given `EPERM` if you try to unlock a lock you have not locked. Perhaps the C++ standards authors included `operation_not_permitted` by a mistaken reading of the POSIX manual page. As C++ has no concept of lock "permissions", it is hard to see how any correctly constructed and manipulated lock (used in accordance with the C++ standard, without invoking any undefined behaviour) could result in `EPERM` and thus `operation_not_permitted`.

`device_or_resource_busy` is not permitted from C++17, which suggests it never really happens in practice, and its inclusion for C++11 was an error.

To summarize, the only cases in which `std::mutex::lock()` could throw an exception indicate program bugs. So it can be reasonable to assume the method "never" throws an exception.

Comment: Unfortunetly the device_or_resource_busy occurs in some mysterious case in visual studio (2017) compiled code, I withess it.

Answer (score 8):

The `std::mutex::lock()` member function is not declared as `noexcept` and from section *30.4.1.2 Mutex types* of the c++11 standard (draft n3337), clause 6:

> The expression `m.lock()` shall be well-formed and have the following semantics:
>
> - ...
> - Throws: `system_error` when an exception is required (30.2.2).
> - Error conditions:
>
>   - `operation_not_permitted` — if the thread does not have the privilege to perform the operation.
>   - `resource_deadlock_would_occur` — if the implementation detects that a deadlock would occur.
>   - `device_or_resource_busy` — if the mutex is already locked and blocking is not possible.

This implies that any function that uses `mutex::lock()` cannot be marked `noexcept`, unless that function is capable of handling the exception itself and prevents it from propogating to the caller.

---

I am unable to comment on the likelihood of these error conditions occuring, but in relation to `std::mutex` and `resource_deadlock_would_occur` (which *might* be thrown) it indicates a bug in the code as opposed to a runtime a failure as this error *might* be raised if a thread attempts to lock a `std::mutex` it already owns. From section *30.4.1.2.1 Class mutex*, clause 4:

> [ Note: A program may deadlock if the thread that owns a mutex object calls lock() on that object. If the implementation can detect the deadlock, a resource_deadlock_would_occur error condition may be observed. —end note ]

By selecting `std::mutex` as the lock type the programmer is explicitly stating that an attempt by the same thread to lock a `mutex` it already has locked is not possible.
It if is a legal path of execution for a thread to re-lock a `mutex` then a [`std:recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) is the more appropriate choice (but changing to a `recursive_lock` does not mean the `lock()` function is exception free).

Comment: I was aware resource_deadlock_would_occur can be throw, but i can (should) prevent this one to happen, since, as you said, it means a bug. So it seams I can't do anything for the two other. Since aborting isn't an alternative, I'll have to handle them :)

Comment: `device_or_resource_busy` apparently not permitted from C++17. Which suggests it never really happens in practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to assume that the mutex won't throw if you can *guarantee* that none of the error conditions (as outlined in hmjd's answer) are present. How to put that call into a noexcept function depends on how you want to handle an (pretty impossible) failure. If the default of noexcept (to call [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is acceptable, you don't need to do anything. If you want to do log the impossible error, wrap the function in a try/catch clause.